# NavigationController unable to show back button in Detailed View Controller when Search Controller is active

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a search controller, when the search controller is active and cell is selected it passes the data to a detailed view controller.

All the data is passed, but there is no back navigation button present on the top left, if the search controller is inactive and the cell is selected the back navigation button is present, and it brings it back to the search and works perfectly for that scenario.

Here's the code for `didSelectRowAt`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let DvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostTableDetailed") as! PostTableDetailed

    var user = usersArray[indexPath.row]

    if(self.searchController.isActive) {
        user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]

        let title = user?.value(forKey: "title")
        print(title)
        DvC.getName = title as! String

        let image = user?.value(forKey: "image")
        print(image)
        DvC.getImg = image as! String

        let desc = user?.value(forKey: "description")
        print(desc)
        DvC.getDesc = desc as! String

        var contact = user?.value(forKey: "contact")
        print(contact)
        if contact == nil {
            contact = ""
        } else {
            DvC.getContact = contact as! String
        }

        let address = user?.value(forKey: "address")
        print(address)
        DvC.getAddress = address as! String

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)
    }
    else {
        user = usersArray[indexPath.row]
        print(user!)

        let title = user?.value(forKey: "title")
        print(title)
        DvC.getName = title as! String

        let image = user?.value(forKey: "image")
        print(image)
        DvC.getImg = image as! String

        let desc = user?.value(forKey: "description")
        print(desc)
        DvC.getDesc = desc as! String

        var contact = user?.value(forKey: "contact")
        print(contact)
        if contact == nil {
            contact = ""
        } else {
            DvC.getContact = contact as! String
        }

        let address = user?.value(forKey: "address")
        print(address)
        DvC.getAddress = address as! String

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check for if you have added two navigation controllers Or might be you are hiding back button.

Comment: Definitely not hiding the back button, and it's a single navigation controller.

Comment: Where exactly is your search bar? Is it on the navigation bar or below the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

try to add UISearchBar as navigation title view in navigation bar